# Listview click for background of a header

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview inside of a framelayout and I want a click for the map view
xml is as

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/txt_totalHotels" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_hotelRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" >
        </ListView>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Here I add a Linear-layout with certain height and make it as transparent for the list-view header

I want a click over the google map
I want to disable the click of a listview header and want to click over google map
Please help me for this one

Comment: You have both MapView and ListView overlapping each other further more layout_above property does not work for a FrameLayout.
I suggest you use Linear Layout to avoid complexity because in FrameLayout if your MapView is behind your ListView, the onClickListener would not trigger for the MapView.

Comment: Thanks sir I will change the code and try to implement this one

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [addHeaderView(View v)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)) to add a whole layout as a scroll-able ListView header, this is if you want the MapView to scroll along with listview.

Try putting mapview in a separate layout file and inflate it to add it as ListView header.

In this case the click function for MapView added as header will be available at ListView.onItemClickListener() at position=0.

In case you don't want your map to scroll with the ListView, you can try putting both the MapView and the ListView in a LinearLayout with spacific weights defined, and then you can add a clicklistener on map.